# How can I grant user data permissions domain-wide for a google apps script web app (non marketplace)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

I have a Google Apps Script Web App distributed to multiple users all in one domain. They trigger it manually via the web app URL available from the publish screen (i.e. it's not a marketplace app).  I'm trying to figure out how to grant user data permissions domain-wide if possible so that users don't have to confront a user data request dialog when it first runs for each given user. FYI they are all on g-suite for business. This is not about "verified app" oath, but about the personal data access permissions. Also, if important, the app is published with  "execute the app as user accessing the web app" because the app needs to pull the email address of the current user in order to function, and on that same screen, access was given to "anyone". I couldn't find this question posed already—apologies if I'm wrong. Thoughts appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If possible please publish add-on app within the domain, it will allow the users.
(You can publish web addon within the domain without any extra cost and permission)
More details  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/domain-wide

Hope it will helpful for you!